# Xamarin MAUI application not shows correct output

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, .net-maui

I have downloaded Visual Studio 2022 Professional (preview) version from
[MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/first-app?pivots=devices-android). Also I have followed the other steps to create first sample application using .Net MAUI template after VS installed.

It does create new project with all the required dependency. I have installed Android sdk api v30 and created a simulator as mentioned in the official document.

When I have run the application on Android Emulator it does take a lot time to run and after it loaded properly it shows wrong output. It's just showing two Hello World label, while MainPage.xaml does have button as well but that button is not displayed. I have attached output screenshot here:

#### MainPage.xaml

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout Spacing="25" Padding="30">

            <Label 
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label 
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label 
                Text="Current count: 0"
                FontSize="18"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                x:Name="CounterLabel"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button 
                Text="Click me"
                FontAttributes="Bold"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                BackgroundColor="Orange" TextColor="White"/>

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                WidthRequest="250"
                HeightRequest="310"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

`Does anyone know what is wrong here in the app? I have followed the steps mentioned in the MS Document which I have mentioned in the question.`

[image]

Comment: you have not posted any code demonstrating what you are doing

Comment: I have not posted it because it's a default code that we got when we create application using .Net Maui templete from microsoft documentation. But now I have update my question please check.

Comment: Unclear what went wrong - I’ve never had that default app fail. **1)** Factory Reset the emulator (VS menu Tools / Android / Android Device Manager - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=macos&pivots=windows#additional-options near bottom of page. **2)** Delete the project/solution you made, and follow the instructions again.

Comment: Try the following steps  : **1.** Delete the app from emulator/device **2.** Delete bin and obj folder   **3.** Reboot visual studio/computer

Comment: I have done these all. Even created new project again but still got the same result.

Comment: Unclear what went wrong . If possible could you provide us a basic, reproducible project to test ?

Comment: it's simple just installed MS 2022 Preview version with MAUI and created one project. With that as default will get MainPage.xaml in that I'm facing this behavior.

Comment: Hi，could you try to deploy the project on Android real device to see if problem persists ? And you can check if it behaves same on another platforms.